BIBO stability and Asymptotic stability
I have difficulty solving these two exercises:
Exercise 1
Consider the system described by the transfer function
$$ P(s)=(s-1)/(s+1)^2 $$
Design a controller so that the feedback controlled system is BIBO stable and type 1
I could do it if the only requirement is that the system be type 1.
In that case I would simply have to multiply the transfer function P(s) by $$G(s)=K_g /s$$ (with Kg a constant ) so as to add a pole at the origin to the system and make it type 1, but how do I solve the point where BIBO stability is asked?
Exercise 2
Consider the system described by the transfer function
$$P(s)= 1/(s-1)^2$$
Design a controller such that the closed-loop system is asymptotically stable and has $$|e_1|<=0.01$$.
In this case I would know how to proceed to solve the point $$|e_1|<=0.01$$ but I would not know how to solve as regards the asymptotic stability, could you help me ?

Please attempt a solution

What is the definition of BIBO stability?

@TimWilliams In order for the system to be BIBO stable all of its poles must have negative real part

OK. And what is the system's TF?

@VoltageSpike i probably would multiply for a PI controller and then study the stability through hurwitz (?)

@TimWilliams the poles of the first function are both negative, but if i multiply for K_g/s ( because i also need the function to be of type 1 ) then i have a pole which is in 0, and so it would not have negative real part

Something is missing. What is the diagram and equation of a "feedback controlled system"? What is its transfer function, using the G and P shown?

@TimWilliams english is not my first language im sorry, here is the complete text of the exercise in italian https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ox65hzu0j5ga5brhtptm2/Senza-titolo2.jpg?rlkey=6jtgrp7krj279p0k3tx6w1mpt&st=ylazvbmt&dl=0

You need to apply the feedback formula.  See Closed-loop transfer function | Wikipedia for diagram and derivation:

It appears you have P (plant?) instead of G, and G instead of H, so substitute into
$$ H(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)} = \frac{P(s)}{1 + P(s) G(s)} $$
and find the poles/zeroes of \$H(s)\$ to complete the problems.
You should find more context in the current (or proceeding) textbook chapter(s), including definitions of the (feedback) system, symbols in use, etc.

What is G(s) ? When the request was to obtain a type 1 system my professor would just multiply P(s) by G(s)=K_g/s ( with K_g constant ) but what in this case where i'm told to design a controller so that the system is BIBO stable ? What is G(s) in this case?

Either the translation "feedback controlled system" is incorrect, or your professor is incorrect to simply multiply them.

anyways here is the scheme of what my professor means https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/08nhb38qq7lxsnr51k3lu/screen.png?rlkey=gvyfzv8pev3rcj3e4z381qnsj&st=xb6q2pge&dl=0      where P(s) is Plant and G(s) is the function equal to K_g/s (where K_g is a constant)
